# why the npm still need to input OTP even close the 2FA

Tags: npm

I close the 2FA from npm [web](https://www.npmjs.com/settings/user/profile), but when I adduser in terminal, still need to input the OTP, how to disable the OTP in terminal?

```
➜  js git:(main) ✗ npm adduser                              
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
Username: demo
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) demo@gmail.com
Enter one-time password from your authenticator app: 647057
npm ERR! code EOTP
npm ERR! This operation requires a one-time password from your authenticator.
npm ERR! You can provide a one-time password by passing --otp=<code> to the command you ran.
npm ERR! If you already provided a one-time password then it is likely that you either typoed
npm ERR! it, or it timed out. Please try again.
```

what should I do to fix this problem?